# Undefined pathname in js

Tags: javascript

I am trying to extract the base of the url:

```
http://google.com/something --> http://google.com
http://127.0.0.1:8000/something --> http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

When I try and use the following:

```
var pathArray = window.location.pathname;
alert(pathArray);
```

I get `pathArray = undefined`. Note: using `location.hostname` does work here. Why is `.pathname` returning undefined, and how would I get the url base here? Thank you.

**Update**: I used `var pathArray = 'http://' + window.location`.

Comment: Path name does not return the domain name. It returns the pat after the domain name. If you're at `http://example.com/a/b.html`, `window.location.pathname` returns `/a/b.html`. Why not use `window.location`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location
May not work in all browsers, as per usual

I'd just get `window.location` and parse it.

Answer (score -1):

Try window.location.host, it works for http://localhost:8000, so it should work for your case

Comment: `window.location.host` won't return the port number, nor the protocol.

Comment: It does. Testing it in Firefox with Firebug

Comment: On Chrome and Firefox on http://localhost/index.html, using `console.log(window.location.host);` I get `localhost` returned.

Comment: Yes, because it doesnt have port number. Even the solution which you suggested doesnt work for localhost/index.html example. i.e(window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host;). If you want port number for mapped URL in host entries, then you have to explicitly give window.location.port